# How to remove unused objects after matching with another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects and another array of names like the following:

**array of objects as file info objects**

```
[
  { fieldname: 'banner', path: 'banner_img_path' },
  { fieldname: 'logo'  , path: 'logo_img_path'   },
  { fieldname: 'random', path: 'random_img_path' }
]
```

**and here is my array of names**

```
['banner', 'logo']
```

So how can i match or mapping those two variables! note that after mapping or matching, all not used objects should be deleted from the original array of objects?? i need to get object like that

```
{
  banner: banner_img_path,
  logo  : logo_img_path
}
```

I'm able to do matching but i was stuck with erasing those not used objects.

Note: May be this question is duplicated but only because i don't know what is the name of this operation!
so please forgive me.

Comment: Is it ok to build that object and then rebuild your original array of objects?

Comment: Not sure why you need to erase anything. It looks like you want a new object created

Comment: @charlietfl It sounds like a poorly worded two-fold question. 1. is to build the object and then 2. delete elements in the original array that don't appear in the object.

Comment: @Andrew but that is assumption based on poor question also

Comment: Still i need to get rid of the not used objects.
It is image i want to delete it if it is not mentioned its name in the array!
So may be you can do it but how ?!

Comment: @Andrew it is files object so it is already created. i need to do matching and then delete unused images.

Comment: Whenever you have an array on input and you expect an array on output, where some elements are removed, think of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You really need to simply filter the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution by using functional native JavaScript functions.

```js
const obj = [
  { fieldname: 'banner', path: 'banner_img_path' },
  { fieldname: 'logo', path: 'logo_img_path' },
  { fieldname: 'random', path: 'random_img_path' },
  { fieldname: 'other', path: 'random_img_path' }
];

const names = ['banner', 'logo'];

obj.map((o, i) => {
 let match = false;
  names.some((item) => {
   if (item === o.fieldname) {
     match = true;
     return true;  
    }
  });
  if (!match) {
   delete obj[i];
  }
});
 

for (let o in obj) {
 document.querySelector('p').innerHTML += obj[o].fieldname + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thanks it seems that your code is more browser friendly. i appreciate you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I add the names you want to keep into a set for lookup. I then use forEach and check inside each object if the `fieldname` matches anything in the set of names. If there's a match, I add it to my `newObj`.

```js
const namesToKeep = ['banner', 'logo']
const fileInfo = [
  { fieldname: 'banner', path: 'banner_img_path' },
  { fieldname: 'logo'  , path: 'logo_img_path'   },
  { fieldname: 'random', path: 'random_img_path' }
]

const names = new Set(namesToKeep)
const newObj = {}

fileInfo.forEach(obj => {
  if (names.has(obj.fieldname)) {
    newObj[obj.fieldname] = obj.path
  }
})
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: I think `fileInfo` determines which names to keep tho.

Comment: If namesToKeep had an element called tester, then tester should be spliced out cos it isnt part of fileInfo

Comment: @JohanP I don't think there's anything wrong with my interpretation of the question. He's posted a specific desired output in the question. Mine is the exact same as it.

Comment: @Andrew After seeing your first code i got inspiration of solving it after modifying your first code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohanP Also Thanks to you.

Comment: Work like charm.

Comment: @Andrew your interpretation of the question is wrong. Your result is purely due to Op's limited example

Comment: @JohanP Mind showing me what you mean? The question has been solved and the accepted answer uses the same principles/interpretation as mine. Perhaps a small js fiddle. My only [perceived?] mistake is that I was using the wrong data structure.